# sharepoint bind managed metadata field to term

Tags: sharepoint

how can I bind a managed metadata field to a Term (not a TermSet) in C#?
The term contains subterms.

I can see that it's possible through the GUI, however in C#, if I do this:
taxonomyField.TermSetId = parentTermSet.Terms["subTermName"].Id;

it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can successfully bind the field to the parent termset, just not to the term within the termset

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, you need to bind the TaxonomyField.AnchroId to the Term's GUID, as well as the TaxonomyField.TermSetId to the TermSet's GUID.